# can you use msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail to set up calendar appointments?

Tags: sql-server

For example, in health care, every employee gets a PPD test (they jab your arm with something) and you have to go back in 48 hours to see if you've sprouted an extra head.

Everybody forgets.

The nurses document in their EHR that they jabbed the patient, and I can send out an email reminding the employee to go check for their extra head, but I'd rather make it a calendar invite.

**Question**

How would you set up an outlook calendar appointment from SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(I dont have outlook to test it .. so the code is not tested by me)*

Borrowed from : [Send Outlook Calendar Requests in Email](http://sqlcodespace.blogspot.com/2015/03/send-outlook-calendar-requests-in-email.html)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
  @recipients ='<your email address>'    
  ,@subject = 'iCalendar Example'    
  , @query = 'SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT ''BEGIN:VCALENDAR''+ CHAR(13)+ ''VERSION:2.0''+ CHAR(13)+ ''METHOD:PUBLISH''+ CHAR(13)+ ''BEGIN:VEVENT''+ CHAR(13)+ ''CLASS:PUBLIC''+ CHAR(13)+ ''DESCRIPTION:This is the iCalendar example Most client application support it''+ CHAR(13)+ ''SUMMARY:iCalendar''+ CHAR(13)+ ''DTEND:20150325T110000''+ CHAR(13)+ ''DTSTART:20150325T120000''+ CHAR(13)+ ''LOCATION:My Office''+ CHAR(13)+ ''END:VEVENT''+ CHAR(13)+ ''END:VCALENDAR'''   
  , @attach_query_result_as_file = 1   
  , @query_result_header = 0   
  , @query_result_separator = 'CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)'   
  , @exclude_query_output = 1   
  , @query_attachment_filename = '123.ics'
```

Comment: This method will not work because mail clients such as Outlook won't recognize the message as a calendar invitations, due to incorrect message headers. The solution must be implemented using something that can modify message headers before sending it, and the only option is CLR. I've recently developed an open-source solution in CLR for sending calendar invitations (ical / ics) from within SQL Server. This works: https://github.com/EitanBlumin/sql_clr_ics

Comment: Do you get any specific error ?

Comment: No, it doesn't show any error. What simply happens is that the invitation is received as a regular e-mail message + the ics file as an attachment. But it's not recognized as a calendar event (i.e. the Accept, Tentative, Decline buttons don't show up).

Answer (score 2):

I've recently developed an open-source solution in CLR for sending calendar invitations (ical / ics) from within SQL Server.

This works:

https://github.com/EitanBlumin/sql_clr_ics